# React request to wrong endpoint

Tags: reactjs, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

my react app is running on [www.frontend.com](http://www.frontend.com) it makes an API request to the backend server https://backend.com.

I opened the network tab in developers tools, it's making a request to forntend.com/undefined instead of backend.com.

in .env

```
API_URL='https://backend.com'
```

```
const endpoint = process.env.API_URL
const client = new GraphQLClient(endpoint)
```

dockerfile

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY .env ./
RUN npm install env-cmd -g --silent
RUN env-cmd -f .env npm install --silent
RUN env-cmd -f .env npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
COPY . ./
RUN env-cmd -f .env npm run build
```

What are the possible reasons for this?

Comment: Can you share the code where the API request is being made? 
Also, if you are using Axios than check you base URL config

Comment: What's the main container `CMD`?  If the frontend is a browser application, is there something that "bakes in" values to `process.env` (the browser won't have access to environment values normally)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you restarted the environment after you added the `API_URL` inside the .env? Normally it returns `undefined` when the Node.js does not detect a newly variable. Try to restart.

Comment: I'm actually running it in a docker. I'm updating the docker file in the question.

Comment: the main issue is it makes the call to frontend.com instead of backend.com